# Django HttpResponse renders html when content_type='application/json'

Tags: ajax, json, django

I'm tying to make an ajax call with jquery to a django view. This view query an external API and then returns the result. I am trying to return the data and manipulate it in the success callback in the ajax call, but instead I am getting a rendered html website showing the content of the response. Here is my code.

My form:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get" action="/search/">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

My ajax call:

```
$('#btn-search').click(function() {
        var params = {
            'query': $('#search').val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            data: params,
            url: JS_URLS['search'],
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
})
```

My view:

```
def search(request):
    if request.GET:
        params = {
            'name'   : request.GET['search'],
        }
        encoded_params = urllib.urlencode(params)
        response = execute_request(url)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

What I get:

[image]

Obviously, the response is not being returned to the ajax function because I don't get the alert message set in both the success and error callbacks.

Comment: If `#search` is an `a` element, you need to prevent the default action. Are you doing this?

Comment: Have you tried calling url any other way, such as from browser or curl?

Answer (score 0):

As data you send `params`, which has `query` as keyword, and not `search`. So you probally get a KeyError, because you don't have `search` set within you querystring. And this returns a Django's yellow error page, which is html.
And check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

Form submission via `GET` causes a reload event in your browser.

You have to prevent the default behaviour of your form, the right place to do this is the form element itself.

Give your form an ID:

```
<form id="mysearchform" class="form-inline" method="get" action="/search/">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

Change the javascript to:

```
$("#mysearchform").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var params = {
            'query': $('#search').val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            data: params,
            url: JS_URLS['search'],
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

The important thing here is to prevent the further execution of default form submission behaviour. `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` take care of that.

You don't need a form at all for what you're trying to do:

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default">SEARCH</button>
```

Change the javascript to:

```
$("#btn-search").click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: JS_URLS['search']+'?query='+$('#search').val(),
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

This will also work in a form, but don't put `type="submit"` on it.

Comment: "Form submission via POST causes a reload event in your browser." I am not using post to submit the form. I have tried your code and I am getting the same behaviour.I still think that the problem is on the server side. The ajax call is being executed properly and I receive the necessary information in the django view, but when I return the value with "return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')" the response renders en empty page with just the json returned. For what I can read in the Django docs, having content_type set to application/json should do the job.

Comment: It's 100% not on the server side. It's impossible for the server to turn a non ajax call into an ajax call or vice versa.

Comment: ditch the form, it's causing problems.

Comment: I have simplified the code to the simplest I could think of and still the same. In the ajax call I am not passing params (thus I am not using anything from the form). In my django view I am querying the external api with a hardcoded url that I know it works. I still get the response rendered on a page as in the attached image.